# Radial text annotation polar plot with clockwise direction

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates, plot-annotations

I want to place some text on a radius of a polar plot. When using the default theta zero location and direction it works as expected

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.set_yticklabels("")
ax.annotate('test',
            xy=(np.deg2rad(90), 0.5),
            fontsize=15,
            rotation=90)
```

[image]

However this fails when changing the direction

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_yticklabels("")
ax.annotate('test',
            xy=(np.deg2rad(90), 0.5),
            fontsize=15,
            rotation=90)
```

[image]

It seems that the x and y are correct but the rotation angle is not. In theory, the transformation between clockwise and anti-clockwise should bring theta into -theta but that obviously does not work here. I have tried any possible transformation but it seems that something weird is happening..

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rotation angle will follow the opposite of the position angle, starting from 90 (at position 0 you have an angle of 90°). Furthermore you can take `angle % 180` to avoid having text upside down:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

angle = 135

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N") # apply +90° rotation
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)      # set - before angle
ax.set_yticklabels("")
ax.annotate('test',
            xy=(np.deg2rad(angle), 0.5),
            fontsize=15,
            rotation=90-(angle % 180))

plt.show()
```

Output for `angle=135`:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, after writing the issue I came up with this solution

def find_rot_angle(x):
    if x <= 180:
        return 450 - x
    else:
        return 270 - x

I believe the "problem" is that, while the whole system is rotated by 90 degrees and reflected around the vertical axis when changing the theta zero location and direction, the annotation rotation is still referred to the original frame of reference so one needs to do this transformation. Honestly I find it very confusing but that's the way it is...

Comment: Indeed the rotation of the text is still defined from a horizontal line. Your function is equivalent to using the modulo operator (`%`). Why 450 and not 90 though? Also it might not give correct results for negative values or values > 360.

Comment: I tried to use 90 - angle but alone that was not working so I computed the transformation equivalent to a 90 degrees rotation + reflection, that's what brought me to that 450. Anyway, it doesn't matter, your approach is better. I'm just wondering if this should be clarified into the doc because I haven't found anything where this is mentioned...and it is confusing. Not sure it is intendend behaviour